# "uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int" - declared "uniqueidentifier" everywhere

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create this table, but I am getting the error 'uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int'.

```
DECLARE @LastFinancialWeek date
SET @LastFinancialWeek = '2020-11-06'

CREATE TABLE #DistinctBookings
(
    BookerCustomerKey INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    HotelKey INT NULL,
    ReservationNumber INT NULL,
    PostImpressionReservationDate DATE NULL
)

INSERT INTO #DistinctBookings
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DBL.BookerCustomerKey
    , DDC.CustomerId
    , DBL.HotelKey
    , DBL.ReservationNumber
    , DBL.ReservationDate AS PostImpressionReservationDate
FROM fact.DailyBookingsLatest DBL
     join Dim.Customer DDC on BookerCustomerKey = DDC.CustomerKey
     -- change reservation date here to start of financial week
WHERE ReservationDate >= @LastFinancialWeek
```

The [CustomerID] is declared Uniqueidentifier in DDC. The other data types each match up with the data types in the tables (DDC and DBL). I have created other tables using [CustomerID] without issue, so I'm unsure what's happening.

Comment: What is the datatype of DDC.CustomerKey?? Is it INT? if not you have an issue

Comment: Show us the definitions of `[fact].[DailyBookingsLatest]` and `[Dim].[Customer]` please

Comment: DDC.CustomerKey is data type INT

Comment: [fact].[DailyBookingsLatest] and [Dim].[Customer] are tables within the table base (ones I haven't set up). What is it precisely you're looking for?

Comment: In your #DistinctBookings table change [BookerCustomerKey] column to be uniqueidentifier type.

Comment: I tried that, and it hasn't worked. It also didn't work when changing CustomerID to INT

Comment: What precisely I'm looking for is the definitions of `[fact].[DailyBookingsLatest]` and `[Dim].[Customer]`. You know, what you'd get if you right-click them in SSMS and choose 'script CREATE to new window'

Comment: Could you provide the structure of the other tables  [fact].[DailyBookingsLatest] and [Dim].[Customer]. It is possible to have an issue with implicit conversion in JOINs.

Comment: @AakashM I have only been using SQL for less than a year, so please excuse me if I don't necessarily understand everything.

Comment: @GeorgianaHC you can execute this command to see table structure:

sp_columns 'DailyBookingsLatest', 'fact'

Same for the Dim.Customer. Please provide TYPE_NAME for BookerCustomerKey and CustomerKey columns in these tables.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are getting an issue because of two reasons:

- Your columns in **SELECT** statement have different data types then you newly created #DistinctBookings table
- Columns used in **JOIN** doesn't have the same data type and implicit conversion is not possible

In the end, when you try to execute your query you are getting an error message: `Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int`.

Steps to reproduce:

- Try to execute SELECT * statement without manually entered and remove INSERT INTO statement above, if it works problem is joining tables
- Leave SELECT *, and try to comment out join by join to see are you still getting an error in implicit conversion.

With these steps, you will easily find what is your problem in the future.

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful! I was able to SELECT without issue, so that told me the issue was with the joining. I think the issue was because I hadn't pointed the join at the correct customer key.